# JPA Criteria ParameterExpression - QueryException Named parameter [ard] not set

Tags: jpa

I try executing a dynamic query using `ParameterExpression` but get an exception.

my method:

```
public List<Atividade> buscarAtividades(Armario armario) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Atividade> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Atividade.class);
    Root<Atividade> atividade = criteriaQuery.from(Atividade.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(atividade);
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();        

    if(armario != null){            
        ParameterExpression<Armario> ard = builder.parameter(Armario.class, "ard");         
        predicates.add(builder.equal(atividade.get("armario").get("numero"), ard));             
    }

    criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    TypedQuery<Atividade> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    return query.getResultList();

}
```

When my query is executed I receive stack:

```
fev 02, 2017 11:31:49 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{cadastroAtividadeBean.buscarAtividades}: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cadastroAtividadeBean.buscarAtividades}: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1307)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
    at com.vivo.tecnico.repository.AtividadesRepository.buscarAtividades(AtividadesRepository.java:49)
    at com.vivo.tecnico.controller.CadastroAtividadeBean.buscarAtividades(CadastroAtividadeBean.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 29 more

fev 02, 2017 11:31:49 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ard] not set
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1307)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
    at com.vivo.tecnico.repository.AtividadesRepository.buscarAtividades(AtividadesRepository.java:49)
    at com.vivo.tecnico.controller.CadastroAtividadeBean.buscarAtividades(CadastroAtividadeBean.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 29 more
```

Any idea where is might be a problem ?

I looking for many post about but always stack.

Armario.class

```
package com.vivo.tecnico.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Armario {

private Long id;
private String numero;
private String endereco;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Armario other = (Armario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Atividade.class

```
package com.vivo.tecnico.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Atividade {
private Long id;
private String numero;
private String cidade;
private Armario armario;
private Date dataAtividade;
private Date dataEncerramento;
private String endereco;
private Funcionario funcionario;
private Causa causa;
private Segmento segmento;

private Status status;

private String observacao;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "armario")
public Armario getArmario() {
    return armario;
}

public void setArmario(Armario armario) {
    this.armario = armario;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "data_atividade")
public Date getDataAtividade() {
    return dataAtividade;
}

public void setDataAtividade(Date dataAtividade) {
    this.dataAtividade = dataAtividade;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "data_encerramento")
public Date getDataEncerramento() {
    return dataEncerramento;
}

public void setDataEncerramento(Date dataEncerramento) {
    this.dataEncerramento = dataEncerramento;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "funcionario_id")
public Funcionario getFuncionario() {
    return funcionario;
}

public void setFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario) {
    this.funcionario = funcionario;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Causa getCausa() {
    return causa;
}

public void setCausa(Causa causa) {
    this.causa = causa;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Segmento getSegmento() {
    return segmento;
}

public void setSegmento(Segmento segmento) {
    this.segmento = segmento;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getObservacao() {
    return observacao;
}

public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
    this.observacao = observacao;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Atividade other = (Atividade) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add code for Atividade and Armario class

Comment: Added the class.
In fact I'd like to create a filter for a dynamic query, but even just creating an attribute of the Atividade class I get parameter error. tnx

Answer (score 2):

When you define a parameter in a Criteria query (`builder.parameter(Armario.class, "ard")` which creates a parameter with name `ard`) you then need to set the value of the parameter to use when running it.

In your case this means

```
query.setParameter("ard", someValue);
```

before calling `query.getResultList()`.

Comment: tnx a lot Niel, I'II try latter.

Comment: presumably you would have tried by now ... more than a month later. So accept the answer that fixed it

Comment: So "ACCEPT" the answer (the tick symbol)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ParameterExpression like this:
assume that you have some input filter, an example could be this:

- in your query you have to check the value of a fiscal Code.

**1)** inizialize a predicateList(use for where clause) and a paramList(use for param)

```
Map<ParameterExpression,String> paramList = new HashMap();
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**2** )check if the input is null and create predicateList and param

```
if( input.getFilterCF() != null){
            //create ParameterExpression
            ParameterExpression<String> cf = cb.parameter(String.class);


           //if like clause
            predicateList.add(cb.like(root.<String>get("cf"), cf));
            paramList.put(cf , input.getFilterCF() + "%");

           //if equals clause
           //predicateList.add(cb.equal(root.get("cf"), cf));   
           //paramList.put(cf,input.getFilterCF()());
        }
```

**3**) create the where clause

```
 cq.where(cb.and(predicateList.toArray(new   Predicate[predicateList.size()])));
TypedQuery<Tuple> q = _em.createQuery(cq);
```

**4**) set param value

```
        for(Map.Entry<ParameterExpression,String> entry : paramList.entrySet())
        {
            q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the associated entity to access its fields for operation like adding filter or cascading the joins. Also if you are adding a parameter to query, set the parameter before executing it.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Atividade> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(c.class);
Root<Atividade> atividade = criteriaQuery.from(Atividade.class);
criteriaQuery.select(atividade);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
Join<Atividade, Armario> armarioJoin = atividade.join("armario", JoinType.INNER)
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();        

if(armario != null){            
    ParameterExpression<Armario> ard = builder.parameter(String.class, "ard");         
    predicates.add(builder.equal(armarioJoin.get("numero"), ard));             
}

criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
TypedQuery<Atividade> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter("ard", armario.getNumero());
return query.getResultList()
```